# flitering multiple Datatables without using regex

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I'm using Datatables 1.10.19 though I would happily upgrade if that will help.

I have an application with several tables on the same page. For one of those tables I want to offer the user the option to do a negative search. They enter a value and see all the rows that don't have that value.

So far as I can see the search() API allows simple text or regex criteria. I've seen examples such as this.

```
var allTables = $('table.dataTable').DataTable();
 
allTables.column( 0 ).search( 'mySearchTerm', true, false ).draw();
```

Some regex dialects support negative look ahead so regex such as those described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406230/regular-expression-to-match-a-line-that-doesnt-contain-a-word) would allow me to specify negation, but it appears that that the regex engine in use in Datatables does not work with such expressions.

My alternative is to use a filter function which I can establish with this:

```
$.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push()
```

However that seems to be a global construct affecting all tables, which I really don't want.

Any suggestions please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `$.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push()` - but it requires some additional work, to handle the fact (as you point out) that this is a global function, affecting all tables.

The following is not a full implementation, but shows the main points:

**The Approach**

My example uses 2 tables, with hard-coded data in each HTML table.

Each table is initialized as follows:

```js
  $(document).ready(function() {

    // ---- first table with custom search ---------//

    var table_a = $('#example_a').DataTable( {
      pageLength: 10
    } );

    // remove the default DT search events - otherwise
    // they will always fire before our custom event:
    $( "#example_a_filter input" ).unbind();

    // add our custom filter event for table_a:
    $('#example_a_filter input').keyup( function( e ) {
        table_a.draw();
    } );

    // ---- second table with DT default search ----//

    var table_b = $('#example_b').DataTable( {
      pageLength: 10
    } );

  } );
```

For my custom search function, I make use of the fact that the function includes a `settings` parameter which we can use to see which table is being searched:

```js
  $.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push (
    function( settings, searchData, index, rowData, counter ) {

      var tableID = settings.nTable.id;
      var searchTerm = $('#' + tableID + '_filter input').val()

      //console.log( tableID );
      //console.log( searchTerm );
      //console.log( searchData );

      switch(tableID) {
        case 'example_a':
          if (searchTerm === '') {
            return true;
          } else {
            show_me = true;
            searchData.forEach(function (item, index) {
              if (show_me && item.includes(searchTerm)) {
                show_me = false;
              }
            });
            return show_me;
          }
          break;
        default:
          // for all other tables, pass through the rows
          // already filtered by the default DT filter:
          return true;
      }
    }
  );
```

The following line is where we ID which table is being filtered:

```
var tableID = settings.nTable.id;
```

After that, I can use a `switch` statement to handle each table's search separately.

In the default case (for `example_b`), I'm just passing through what was already filtered by the DT default search:

```
default: return true;
```

The above filter looks like this when I search each table for the letter `x`:

[image]

**Incomplete Implementation**

This logic is incomplete for the custom search logic. It assumes the search term is a single string. If I enter "x y" in the input field, that will exclude all records where a field contains "x y" - which is probably not what you want.

You probably want the exact negation of the standard search - so the input term would need to be split on spaces and each sub-term (`x` and `y`) would need to be checked separately across each row of data.

Comment: Thank you; this answers my question, and gives nicely detailed examples that surely will be helpful to others.